# A song played on episode 487 when Trafalgar Law turns up at Marineford

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the music that plays when Trafalgar Law turns up at Marineford in episode 487? I can't seem to find it anywhere online.

Answer (score 1):

The track when law appears is called "Luffy vs Ratchet, Round 1".